Setting large fs.pipe-max-size
When I increase fs.pipe-max-size like so:
echo "fs.pipe-max-size = N" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p

(N is ~4-10Mbytes)
And use F_SETPIPE_SZ to change named pipe sizes to N, sometimes it fails with "operation not permitted" error.
The system has ~20 pipes and I set the same pipe buffer size on all of them.
The question is:

is it because I hit some kind of a total kernel pipe buffer memory capacity (btw the system has 30G RAM)?
Or is it because I use N that isn't divisible by a page size so F_SETPIPE_SZ might set the size above the fs.pipe-max-size limit and it will fail as "operation not permitted"? Makes sense, I think I saw in logs values larger than I asked.
Or is it something totally else?


the man page fcntl(2) appears to say "In the current implementation, the
allocation is the next higher power-of-two page-size
multiple of the requested size.", so it's not just being a multiple of the page size, but indeed means you might get more than you ask. What were the actual sizes  you used?

In the kernel implementation that handles the fcntl() system call on a pipe, there's:
    /*
     * If trying to increase the pipe capacity, check that an
     * unprivileged user is not trying to exceed various limits
     * (soft limit check here, hard limit check just below).
     * Decreasing the pipe capacity is always permitted, even
     * if the user is currently over a limit.
     */
    if (nr_slots > pipe->max_usage &&
            size > pipe_max_size && !capable(CAP_SYS_RESOURCE))
        return -EPERM;

    user_bufs = account_pipe_buffers(pipe->user, pipe->nr_accounted, nr_slots);

    if (nr_slots > pipe->max_usage &&
            (too_many_pipe_buffers_hard(user_bufs) ||
             too_many_pipe_buffers_soft(user_bufs)) &&
            pipe_is_unprivileged_user()) {
        ret = -EPERM;
        goto out_revert_acct;
    }

Those EPERMs correspond to the "operation not permitted" errors that you're seeing.
I think it's likely you're hitting an unprivileged user resource limit.  You can do a man 7 pipe and search for /proc file for the details, but here's a quick summary:

  /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size (since Linux 2.6.35)
         The maximum size (in bytes) of individual pipes that can
         be set by users without the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.

  /proc/sys/fs/pipe-user-pages-hard (since Linux 4.5)
         The hard limit on the total size (in pages) of all pipes
         created or set by a single unprivileged user (i.e., one
         with neither the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE nor the CAP_SYS_ADMIN
         capability).

  /proc/sys/fs/pipe-user-pages-soft (since Linux 4.5)
         The soft limit on the total size (in pages) of all pipes
         created or set by a single unprivileged user (i.e., one
         with neither the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE nor the CAP_SYS_ADMIN
         capability).


